# Don't display remote notification?

Tags: ios, push-notification

I'm performing some logic to determine whether to display a notification in my `didReceiveRemoteNotification` function. In the case where I want to show no notification how do I show no alert?

If I don't include a completion handler I get the error `Application delegate received call to -application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called.`

Adding `completionHandler([])` or `completionHandler(nil)` says I need to pass in a `UIBackgroundFetchResult` to the completion handler. How do I not display the received remote notification?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're looking for a Silent Notification. They can be used to inform the application of new content without having the user informed. Instead of displaying a notification alert, the application will be awakened in background and application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: will be called. You then have the opportunity to process any information transparently for the user :

Download some content
Synchronize some elements,
Inform the user directly within the application when he opens it back
Note that your time is limited to 30s.

To configure silent notifications

> To support silent remote notifications, add the remote-notification
>   value to the UIBackgroundModes array in your Info.plist file.

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

Configuring a Silent Notification

> The aps dictionary can also contain the content-available property.
>   The content- available property with a value of 1 lets the remote
>   notification act as a silent notification. When a silent notification
>   arrives, iOS wakes up your app in the background so that you can get
>   new data from your server or do background information processing.
>   Users aren’t told about the new or changed information that results
>   from a silent notification, but they can find out about it the next
>   time they open your app.

For a silent notification, take care to ensure there is no alert, sound, or badge payload in the aps dictionary. If you don’t follow this guidance, the incorrectly-configured notification might be throttled and not delivered to the app in the background, and instead of being silent is displayed to the user

Comment: well, you'd need to put that logic in the server